# How to generate a random Hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, random

From Derbyshire's *Prime Obsession*, I would like to get the Mathematica code to generate a Hermitian matrix for evaluation and display. $ 256 \times 256 $ would be nice.
Random Normal distribution, eigenvalues, etc.  All or part code. Any references?
I am but a humble novice.  New to StackExchange. Thanks.

Comment: Were you referring to [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=A-cg6DdryysC&pg=PA285)? BTW, the current version now has `GaussianUnitaryMatrixDistribution[]`.

Comment: Thanks:  I have Mathematica 10.3 including GaussianUnitaryMatrixDistribution[].   Didn't know I had it, but I do.

Answer (score 4):

If I had interpreted you correctly, here's my attempt to do the figures [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=A-cg6DdryysC&pg=PA285):

```
n = 269; k = 10;
mat = RandomVariate[GaussianUnitaryMatrixDistribution[n]];
eig = Sort[Eigenvalues[mat], LessEqual];
{p, q} = MinMax[eig]; h = (q - p)/k;
bins = BinLists[eig, {p, q, h}];

zer = Im[N[ZetaZero[Range[n]]]];
{zp, zq} = MinMax[zer]; zh = (zq - zp)/k;
zbins = BinLists[zer, {zp, zq, zh}];

{Graphics[Point[Flatten[MapIndexed[{#1 - h (#2[[1]] - 1), #2[[1]]} &, bins, {2}], 1]],
          AspectRatio -> 1], 
 Graphics[Point[Flatten[MapIndexed[{#1 - zh (#2[[1]] - 1), #2[[1]]} &, zbins, {2}], 1]],
          AspectRatio -> 1]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: they do look similar, don't they?]

Comment: JM
Thanks. The code is a big help.
Don

Comment: JM On further review the code in your answer was tight and elegant.